# Menu-link only works on index.html and no other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason my menu link doesn't work on any other page except for the index page. I think its a problem within JavaScript but I'm not quite sure. The HTML navigation section of the page not working is the exact same as the code for index.html. Here is the CSS

```
.list-menu {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.list-menu.reveal-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-menu .ion-close-round {
  font-size: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.circle {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index:99 ;
  padding: 0px 0 0;
}



.circle i {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #111112;
}

.circle.dark {
  border-color: #292929;
}

.circle.dark:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #292929;
}

.circle.large {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.circle.large:before {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 31.0px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
}

.circle.large.dark:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #292929;
}

.circle.inline {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .circle.large {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: -45px
    ;
  }
  .circle.large:before {
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 25.0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  }
}
```

and the JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            
    "use strict";

    $('.menu-container').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('.circle').attr('menu-link', index);
        $(this).find('.list-menu').clone().appendTo('body').attr('menu-link', index);
    });

    $('.menu-container .circle').click(function() {
        var linkedVideo = $('section').closest('body').find('.list-menu[menu-link="' + $(this).attr('menu-link') + '"]');
        linkedVideo.toggleClass('reveal-modal');
       
    });

    $('section').closest('body').find('.close-iframe').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.list-menu').toggleClass('reveal-modal');
    });
```

Here is what the popup is supposed to look like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFKr5.jpg

I've been trying to fix for a while but can't seem to find a fix.

Here is also the html for both index.html and hotelam.html
First index

```
<!-- Navigation section ()
================================================== -->
<div class="nav-container">
   <nav class="nav-inner transparent">

      <div class="navbar">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                
              <div class="brand">
                 <a href="home.html">
                <img src="images/Logo4.png" ></a>
            </a>
              </div>

              <div class="navicon">
                <div class="menu-container">

                  <div class="circle dark inline">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-menu">
                    <i class="icon ion-close-round close-iframe"></i>
                    <div class="intro-inner">
                      <ul id="nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </nav>
</div>
```

Second Hotelam.html

```
<!-- Navigation section
================================================== -->
<div class="nav-container">
   <nav class="nav-inner transparent">

      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="color9">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="brand2">
                 <a href="home.html">
                <img src="images/brandl.png" ></a>
            </a>
              </div>

              <div class="navicon">
                <div class="menu-container">

                  <div class="circle dark inline">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-menu">
                    <i class="icon ion-close-round close-iframe"></i>
                    <div class="intro-inner">
                      <ul id="nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing in your JS indicates that the code is only supposed to work on the index page. Could you provide the HTML for the index page and the others?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One of the bullets from the latter includes: "Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: I added the index html and the other page that was not working... There the exact same

Comment: I realized that there was a missing <section> tag in hotelam.html. Thanks so much for the help its working now